# web scraping with selenium on a dynamic table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i'm trying to scrape the table from a dynamic website (it updates information every 10 secs i believe) and load it to a panda dataframe but i can't seem to get pass the first step of getting the first column. can someone advise on what i'm doing wrong? thanks.

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

urlpage = 'https://new.cryptoxscanner.com/binance/live'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\chrome\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(urlpage)
time.sleep(10)
ticker = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="scroll-source-1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need wait until the data located, use `.visibility_of_all_elements_located`. You can use this locator to wait:

```
//table[contains(@class, "table-sm")]//a
```

After all the data located, then you can extract the table data. Try the below code:

```
driver.get('https://new.cryptoxscanner.com/binance/live')

#UPDATED HERE
option = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//select[contains(., "All")]'))))
option.select_by_visible_text('All')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//table[contains(@class, "table-sm")]//a')))
data = driver.find_element_by_class_name('table-responsive')
print(data.text)
```

Following import:

```
#UPDATED HERE
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: thanks alot! the import was missing from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By, but after i added that, it worked great! if i need to change the count from 25 to All before i extract, what do you recommend i use? thanks again for the help!

Comment: @python_rok I'm forget to import `By` :) . And now please see the updated code, I just add `option` before all data loaded. Hope that will help. Don't forget to import `Select`.

Comment: instead of doing a print(data.text), is there a method to convert the data into a panda dataframe? i thought i could figure out how to do this after you helped me get started, but i've been researching this issue for a while now without any success. can you provide some suggestions? thanks.